# Change color of dgrid3d surface in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a way to change the color of the lines of the surface when using dgrid3d? It seem simple enough but everything I've looked at only speaks of coloring the whole surface using pm3d. I have multiple surfaces on one plot and would like to be able to specify the color of each. For example, one would be red, another would be blue, another would be black, another would be green.

Comment: Please show us a short example of what you are doing. Whats wrong with `lc rgb 'blue'` if you want the lines of one surface to be of one color?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data available in a file Data.dat then give this a try:

```
set dgrid3d 10,10
set style data lines
set pm3d 
splot "Data.dat" pal
```

- The `dgrid3d` tells gnuplot how many entries there are in the x- and
  y-direction (those are the two comma separated parameters)
- The `style data lines` lets gnuplot plot the result with lines
  instead of points
- The `pm3d` fills the surface with a color (if you leave this away you
  will just see the lines)
- `pal` makes the lines appear in the color of the specified value

There are much more options you can set, but i find those the most relevant.

Comment: The numbers specify how many elements there are in x- and y-direction. So if you have 20 x-values and 10 y-values then specify the parameters in dgrid as 20, 10

Comment: AFAIK dgrid3d only takes two parameters if you want to specify the number of rows and columns

Comment: `dgrid3d` is only for interpolating scattered data to a regular grid. The two numbers give the number sample which are used for the reconstructed grid, independent of the number of input points. If no number are given, `10,10` is used.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like.

```
set dgrid3d
splot "file.dat" with lines linecolor 4
```

Where 4 is color you need.

For multiple surfaces you can try

```
set dgrid3d splines
set table "surface1.dat"
splot "file1.dat" 
unset table
unset dgrid3d
```

for every surface you need. 
And after all surface description

```
splot "surface1.dat" with lines linecolor 4, splot "surface2.dat" with lines linecolor 7 ...
```

Comment: Oops just haven't notice "multiple surfaces"